# Selecting correct slide and disabling rotation

Tags: jquery, css

I have navigation working with a banner slideshow set up using unslider (unslider.com). I have been unable to figure out how to prevent the "double arrow" from displaying when user hovers over one of the nav options on the right. Also, I have not been able to figure out how to get the appropriate banner to display on left when user hovers over nav option on right. When user hovers over right navigation, I'd like for correct banner to display and the selected navigation to be the only navigation highlighted. When user "un-hovers", it needs to resume as normal.

Code below and working demo here:

http://codepen.io/trevoray/pen/GgPGaB

---

```
  <div id="hp-banner">
   <div id="hp-banner-left" class=banner>
      <ul>
         <li id="image1">
            <a href="/test.php" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 0; position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 100px;"></a>
            <a href="/test.php" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 0; position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 400px;"></a>
         </li>
         <li id="image2"></li>
         <li id="image3"></li>
         <li id="image4"></li>
         <li id="image5"></li>
      </ul>
   </div>

   <div id="hp-banner-right">
      <ul>
         <li><a href="">banner 1</a></li>
         <li><a href="">banner 2</a></li>
         <li><a href="">banner 3</a></li>
         <li><a href="">banner 4</a></li>
         <li><a href="">banner 5</a></li>
      </ul>


   </div>

   <!-- hp banner end -->
</div>
```

---

```
 <style>
   #hp-banner {
      width: 1024px;
   }
   #hp-banner-left {
      float: left;
      width: 680px;
      height: 200px;
   }
   #hp-banner-right ul {
      width: 324px;
      float: left;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
   }
   #hp-banner-right ul li {
      list-style: none;
      line-height: 38px;
      height: 38px;
      background: #f9fafb;
      position: relative;
      color: #8d8d69;
      text-align: center;
      border: solid thin #cbcccc;
   }
   #hp-banner-right ul li:hover,
   #hp-banner-right ul li.active {
      color: white;
      background: #4882c3;
   }
   #hp-banner-right ul li:hover:before,
   #hp-banner-right ul li.active:before {
      content: '';
      border-top: 19px solid transparent;
      border-bottom: 19px solid transparent;
      border-right: 38px solid #4882c3;
      position: absolute;
      right: 100%;
      top: 0;
   }
   .banner {
      position: relative;
      overflow: auto;
      width: 680px;
   }
   .banner ul {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
   }
   .banner li {
      list-style: none;
   }
   .banner ul li {
      float: left;
      display: block;
      max-width: 100%;
      height: 200px;
      /*        -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;*/

      -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
      -o-background-size: 100% 100%;
      -ms-background-size: 100% 100%;
      /*        background-size: 100% 100%;*/
   }
   #image1 {
      background-image: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/189477/image1.jpg");
   }
   #image2 {
      background-image: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/189477/image2.jpg");
   }
   #image3 {
      background-image: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/189477/image3.jpg");
   }
   #image4 {
      background-image: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/189477/image4.jpg");
   }
   #image5 {
      background-image: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/189477/image5.jpg");
   }
</style>
```

---

```
 <script>
   $(function() {
      $('.banner').unslider({
         speed: 500, //  The speed to animate each slide (in milliseconds)
         delay: 2000,
         dots: true,
         complete: function() {
            var index = $('#hp-banner .dot.active').index();
            $('#hp-banner-right li').removeClass('active').eq(index).addClass('active');
         }
      });
   });


   $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#hp-banner-right li').first().addClass('active');
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i didn't use this **"Unslider"**-Plugin before, but i edited your JavaScript Code like this:

**DEMO** http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xGEERV

```
$(function() {
    var slidey = $('.banner').unslider(
    {
      speed: 500,               //  The speed to animate each slide (in milliseconds)
    delay: 2000,
      dots:true,
      complete:function () {
        var index = $('#hp-banner .dot.active').index ();
        $('#hp-banner-right li').removeClass ('active').eq (index).addClass ('active');
      }
    }
    );
  data = slidey.data('unslider');
  $("li").mouseenter(function(){
    $('#hp-banner-right li').not(this).removeClass ('active');
    $(this).addClass ('active');
    var idx = $(this).index();
    data.move(idx, function() {

    });
    data.stop();
  });
  $("#hp-banner-right").mouseleave(function(){
    data.start();
  });

});


 $( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#hp-banner-right li').first().addClass ('active');
});
```